# I'm looking for a 3d grapher that can represent a line whose coordinates only depend on one variable

Tags: graphing-functions

All online graphers I could find could only compute lines whose equations were

$z=f(x,y)$

But what I'm looking for is

$y=f(x), z=g(x)$

So instead of $G_f=\{A(x,y,f(x,y))\}$ I need something like $G_{f,g}=\{A(x,f(x),g(x))\}$

I tried with surface plotters using the equation    $(y-f(x))^2+(z-g(x))^2=0$    but it didn't work because, well, that equation doesn't represent a surface. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your first equation describes a surface, not a line.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KatCPnTNoA&t=268s

Comment: @Andrei Thank you, I tried the site but didn't know about any of the commands, it's really what I was looking for! And yeah I know the first equation describes a surface, my bad :p